# VB script is not getting executed after I changed the path I see Windows script host prompt with a different path

Tags: java, excel, selenium, vbscript, vba

I have created VBS script and am calling it in my Java program. This was working flawlessly until I changed the path.

I see the below error:
[image: here it is]

Things I did:

1. I changed the path in my VBS script

   ```
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("GALE-GoEasy-QA\GoEasy\requiredSource\TestData1.xlsm")

   objExcel.Application.Run "TestData1.xlsm!refreshXLS" 
   objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

   objExcel.Application.Quit
   WScript.Quit
   ```
2. My Java program calls this function to execute the program

   ```
   public void refreshExcelData() throws IOException {

     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
       "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wscript.exe",
       "myVBS.vbs"
     });
   }
   ```

Also I have attached a picture of my project folder structure

[image: Here it is]

PS: I wanted to use relative path instead of absolute

Comment: Try giving full path of vbs file or add that folder path to Environment variable path.

Comment: I had given the full path earlier. But the requirement is to give it an absolute path so that once i push the code to git. Anyone can use it. without changing. Is there a possible to give absolute path to vbs scripts

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\requiredSource\\myVBS.vbs". Use this as path of the file.It will get the current project directory in any machine and run the file.

Comment: Why is there a VB6 tag on this question? The only VB code seems to be VBScript and VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public void refreshExcelData() throws IOException {

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
      "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wscript.exe",
       System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\requiredSource\\myVBS.vbs"‌
   });
}
```